Vite build in docker with WSL2 integration is extremely slow
I'm having a hard time understanding the root cause of Vite build poor performance inside of a docker image that I hope for some guidance here.
Running vite build locally versus inside of a docker has drastic performance differences.
Context
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && vite build -l info -d",
  }
}

Running build on a local machine is fast and finishes in 7seconds

Versus logs from a docker image (failed after ~7mins):

In the end, getting the out of memory exception:
    <--- Last few GCs --->
    
    [17:0x7f00f56d5690]   382491 ms: Scavenge 4002.5 (4127.4) -> 3990.8 (4128.9) MB, 15.96 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.123, current mu = 0.030) allocation failure;
    [17:0x7f00f56d5690]   385497 ms: Mark-Compact 4004.5 (4128.9) -> 3983.8 (4131.1) MB, 2789.26 / 0.00 ms  (average mu = 0.249, current mu = 0.369) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed
    
    
    <--- JS stacktrace --->
    
    FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
    ----- Native stack trace -----
    npm error path /
    npm error command failed
    npm error signal SIGABRT
    npm error command sh -c tsc && vite build -l info -d --profile
    
    npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-10-04T08_13_20_026Z-debug-0.log

Notice the vite:transform and vite:load steps, jumping from ms to ~60sec + ~37sec.
There's nothing special with dockerfile:
FROM node:20.15.1-alpine AS build
ENV GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:20.15.1-alpine

RUN npm i -g serve

COPY --from=build ./dist ./dist

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "serve", "-s", "dist" ]

For vite config:
export default defineConfig(() => ({
  resolve: { alias: { '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src') } },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    vanillaExtractPlugin(),
    consulSelfRegister({ name: 'personal-finances-frontend' })
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    coverage: {
      provider: 'c8',
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html']
    }
  },
  preview: {
    port: 5173,
    strictPort: true
  },
  server: {
    port: 5173,
    strictPort: true,
    host: true,
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5173'
  }
}));

I'm building with docker for windows and WSL2 integration.
Findings
I found that commenting vanillaExtractPlugin() in vite config - solves the issue and build drops to mere 12sec, but for some reason did not produce debug logs - not sure why?

Package versions used:
"@vanilla-extract/css": "^1.16.0",
"@vanilla-extract/vite-plugin": "^4.0.16",

Help needed
So from this point, I'm kinda stuck - is there something that I could check/debug to nail down the root cause of the problem to try and attack it?
Workaround
It seems that there was something strange with the vanilla extract plugin version, - reverting to 3.9.5 resolved the issue ...
This github issue helped me out:
https://github.com/vanilla-extract-css/vanilla-extract/issues/1408

To verify, this is the Dockerfile RUN npm build command that's being slow; no volumes or host-directory mounts are involved here?  Docker Desktop has a "resources" screen with a memory limit, if you're hitting out-of-memory issues then does increasing the Docker VM memory help?

Yep, - that exact step - vite build itself from inside of the docker desktop, no volumes, no mounts. I just found the issue in vanilla extract repo: https://github.com/vanilla-extract-css/vanilla-extract/issues/1408, I was able to resolve the issue by reverting plugin version down to 3.9.5.
It seems that there's an issue with the plugin, rather than docker... But it's still weird why it's only reproducible from within docker...

I've found a reference to similar problems in vanilla extract github: https://github.com/vanilla-extract-css/vanilla-extract/issues/1408
Reverting version to "@vanilla-extract/vite-plugin": "3.9.5" resolved the issue.
But why it was only an issue from within the docker - is still a mystery.
